# Python OpenCV draw contour only on the outside border

Tags: python, opencv, contour

When drawing a contour using OpenCV's `drawContours` the borders is drawn centered to the contour, I want to draw the border only on the outside of the contour.

This image (taken from the SketchUp documentation) explains it best:
[image]

`drawContours` draws the contour like in the first circle (the contour is in the middle of the drawn border). I need to have the border only on the outside of the contour, like in the last circle.

Anyone have an idea as to how can I achieve this kind of behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: OpenCV has no builtin function to do this. If you don't care about performance too much, you can: 1) draw the filled white contour on `mask1`, 2) dilate by 1 on `mask2`, 3) `mask3 = mask1 XOR  mask2`. 4) set the pixels in your image of the color you want using `mask3`.

Comment: Would you always have the inner circle with homogeneous Color, and do you have the information about the color of inside circle, at the point of drawing the contours ?

Answer (score 2):

use the code as

```
  _ret, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
  cv2.drawContours(img,contours , -1, (255,0,0), 1)
```

here cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL gives only the external detected contour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer AdityaIntwala but I am talking about drawing contours and not detecting the contours.

Comment: you need to find the external contour for that..once you find the external contour you can draw the found external contour using drawContours function normally.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the color of the inside core is always homogeneous, and you know the value of the core color beforehand, we can simply do it as:

```
#First you draw the contour on both the sides of the border.
contour_id = 0
border_thickness = 10
border_color = (185, 115, 72)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, contour_id, border_color, border_thickness)

#Now you again draw contour but with thickness = -1 and color = Core color
border_thickness = -1
core_color = (225, 141, 98)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, contour_id, core_color, border_thickness)
```